Hook that executes a verbatim environment from fancyvrb
I am currently making edits to a cls file, and I am trying to figure out a way to include a block of content at the end of a document that is compiled using that cls. Normally I'd use some variant of a hook at the end of the document, like \AtEndDocument (relevant: For reasons beyond my control the machines compiling the file use the last release of tex2019).
Unfortunately, the block of content I want to include, must be wrapped inside a very specific environment, which is defined via a \DefineVerbatimEnvironment like the following:
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{tmpEnv}{Verbatim}{Unimportant Config Tags}

So, what I am after, is some way of automatically always including a block at the end of the document that looks like:
\begin{tmpEnv}
Some content to include at the end of every document using this cls.
\end{tmpEnv}

Obviously, this runs into the problem of embedding a verbatim environment inside hooks, commands, or anything else I have come up with. I've seen the suggestion of using cprotect command, but that appears to only be specifically for in-line verbatim, and not a verbatim style environment.
So, is there a way to write a command or a hook that contains a verbatim environment defined via \DefineVerbatimEnvironment? Or is this one of those areas where verbatim makes everything way more difficult than anyone wants to deal with?
Optionally, the content I'm trying to include needs to be processed by the tex engine, but not displayed on the pdf - so bonus points if you can get the tex engine to "see" the verbatim environment and its content, but not typeset it to the page. [If this seems bizarre, it's because the environment triggers a number of other processing via things like tex4ht and some other stuff, so the code block is mostly there for the other processes at play and not the actual pdf rendering]
EDIT:: To be clear, the problem is that there is a very specific environment that I need to put content into and then hook into the end of the document without requiring the cls user to do anything to make it happen. This is difficult because the environment I need to hook in happens to be a Verbatim Environment defined by the \DefineVerbatimEnvironment. Thus the problem is not simply to include verbatim text at the end of a document - rather I need to figure out how to include a specific environment at the end via a hook or command or something, but that environment is a Verbatim environment which causes issues.

Write the content to a file. Then you can use some inputverbatim command in the hook. And you can do the processing in \setbox0\hbox.

Can you please show a short example of what you need to typeset verbatim? Maybe it can be solved without verbatim mode.

@egreg Unfortunately it's not that the content needs verbatim, it's that I need the tmpEnv wrapper to trigger the content inside to be processed correctly by other tools that I can't change, and that environment wrapper is a verbatim environment.
For what it's worth however, the content is arbitrary javascript code.

so does Ulrike's suggestion work? it's really not clear what 'seeing' the content involves? what do you want the environment to do? do the tools operate on the tex file or the pdf/dvi/whatever? or is the environment as immutable as the tools?

I believe the extra tools search for the environment in the tex file and then process the contents of the environment differently (than how the tex engine itself processes the tex file) when parsing the tex file. This leads me to wonder if I can get around the problem via some kind of detokenize method, where the string "\begin{tmpEnv}" appears, but isn't actually an environment trigger for LaTeX. I haven't gotten to try Ulrike's solution yet, but it's not clear how that works if it still needs to be explicitly between the string "\begin{tmpEnv}" and "\end{tmpEnv}"

Edited original post with a (hopefully) more clear explanation of the problem. It's not about trying to figure out how to include verbatim text at the end of a document via a hook, but rather how to include a specific environment at the end of a document via a hook or some other method - where that environment happens to be a verbatim environment unfortunately.

if the tools parse the tex file themselves and look specifically for that environment, then you have to include that stuff in the appropriate place in the tex file. you can't use latex to rewrite the tex file it's compiling. but then you say the environment must be processed by the tex engine. why? note that it is a different matter if the tools parse some file tex produces such as the .aux or .log or whatever.

(In the question it is said that solutions are to work with older LaTeX releases, too. So with this answer neither xparse nor expl3 was used although this might have made the task considerably easier.
In any case using xparse's resp. ltcmd.dtx's v/+v-argument-type instead of \UDcollectverbarg would make usage of the routines provided less error-prone because with an argument of type v/+v you get error-messages in case the argument is not obtained by reading and tokenizing lines of the .tex-input-file but is passed on from other macros and contains tokens that don't fit the spectrum of tokens that might come into being when .tex-input gets tokenized in verbatim-catcode-régime.)
In the question detailed information about the workflow with the scenario implemented in the documentclass was not revealed, only a vague outline. E.g., it was not revealed how content of the verbatim environment in question comes into being. So with the first two examples of this answer it is assumed that both the content of the environment and the commands for starting and ending the environment can be provided altogether by the programmer of the documentclass in one go.
Placing tokens into a hook for at the end of the document processing tokens that form a verbatim-like environment which should not typeset material only might make sense to me in case the environment, which LaTeX is to process when the end of the document is reached, triggers passing the environment's body to other programs via \write18/\shellesc. The circumstance that this needs to be done at the end of the document, however, might indicate that the content of the environment does not come into being in one go but is accumulated by and by during the LaTeX-run.
So all in all the question forming a variant of the XY-problem cannot be ruled out.
Be that as it may.
If the "number of other processing via things like tex4ht" does not include delayed-writing things to a text file, then placing the environment into a box that itself never gets placed into the document might be an option.
If the "number of other processing via things like tex4ht" does include delayed-writing things to a text file, then placing the environment into a box that is clipped to zero-height, zero-depth and zero-width might be an option. But with all consequences of adding another box to the page. You can use the package trimclip for clipping boxes. However, the manual of the package trimclip says that material/data clipped to invisibility this way ends up in the pdf-file and is just not displayed, but with the right tools for examining pdf-files can be extracted from the pdf-file. With most pdf-viewers doing a simple copy-paste  with the page in question is sufficient for also copying invisible/colorless material.
As it is about processing things verbatimized it is suggested to have things tokenized in verbatim-catcode-régime and passed on to \scantokens for re-tokenization.
This is a variant where the environment in question goes into a box which never gets typeset - this way whatsits in that box for delayed-writing things to external text-file at the time of shipping the page to pdf-file never get carried out:
\makeatletter
%%======================Code for \UDcollectverbarg=============================
%% \UDcollectverbarg{<non-optional 1>}{<non-optional 2>}|<verbatim arg>|
%% 
%% reads <verbatim arg> under verbatim-catcode-regime and delivers:
%%
%%    <non-optional 1>{<non-optional 2>{<verbatim arg>}}
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% \UDcollectverbarg*{<non-optional 1>}{<non-optional 2>}|<verbatim arg>|
%% 
%% reads <verbatim arg> under verbatim-catcode-regime and delivers:
%%
%%    <non-optional 1>{<non-optional 2>{|<verbatim arg>|}}
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Instead of using verbatim-delimiter | or the like the <verbatim arg> can 
%% be nested in braces.
%%
%% You cannot use percent or spaces or horizontal tab as verbatim-delimiter.
%%
%% You can use <non-optional 1> for nesting calls to \UDcollectverbarg.
%%
%% The unstarred variant removes the verbatim-delimiters/braces that surround
%% <verbatim arg>.
%% The starred variant keeps the verbatim-delimiters/braces that surround
%% <verbatim arg>.
%% Reason: When you feed things to \scantokens you don't need the verbatim-
%%         delimiters.
%%         When you use things for writing to temporary files and reading back
%%         verbatimized, you may need them.
%%=============================================================================
\@ifdefinable\UDcollectverbarg{%
  \DeclareRobustCommand\UDcollectverbarg{%
    \@ifstar{\UD@collectverbarg{\@secondoftwo}}{\UD@collectverbarg{\@firstoftwo}}%
  }%
}%
\newcommand\UD@collectverbarg[3]{%
  % #1 - indicator whether to remove/keep the verb-delimiter (\@firstoftwo/\@secondoftwo)
  % #2 - non-optional 1
  % #3 - non-optional 2
  \begingroup
  \let\do\@makeother % <- this and the next line switch to
  \dospecials        %    verbatim-category-code-régime.
  \catcode`\{=1      % <- give opening curly brace the usual catcode so a 
                     %    curly-brace-balanced argument can be gathered in
                     %    case of the first thing of the verbatimized-argument 
                     %    being a curly opening brace.
  \catcode`\ =10     % <- give space and horizontal tab the usual catcode so \UD@@collectverbarg
  \catcode`\^^I=10   %    cannot catch a space or a horizontal tab as its 4th undelimited argument.
                     %    (Its 4th undelimited argument denotes the verbatim-
                     %     syntax-delimiter in case of not gathering a
                     %     curly-brace-nested argument.)
  \catcode`\%=14     % <- make percent comment.
  \kernel@ifnextchar\bgroup
  {% seems a curly-brace-nested argument is to be picked:
    \catcode`\}=2    % <- give closing curly brace the usual catcode also.
    \UD@@collectverbarg{#1}{\@firstoftwo}{#2}{#3}{}%
  }{% seems an argument with verbatim-syntax-delimiter is to be picked:
    \do\{% <- give opening curly brace the verbatim-catcode again.
    \UD@@collectverbarg{#1}{\@secondoftwo}{#2}{#3}%
  }%
}%
\newcommand\UD@@collectverbarg[5]{%
  % #1 - indicator whether to remove/keep the verb-delimiter (\@firstoftwo/\@secondoftwo)
  % #2 - indicator whether braces or verb-delimiter (\@firstoftwo/\@secondoftwo)
  % #3 - non-optional 1
  % #4 - non-optional 2
  % #5 - verb-delimiter or emptiness
  \do\ %   <- Now that \UD@@collectverbarg has the delimiter or
  \do\^^I%    emptiness in its 4th arg, give space and horizontal tab
         %    the verbatim-catcode again.
  \do\^^M% <- Give the carriage-return-character the verbatim-catcode.
  \do\%%   <- Give the percent-character the verbatim-catcode.
  \long\def\@tempb##1#5{%
    #1{\def\@tempb{##1}}{#2{\def\@tempb{{##1}}}{\def\@tempb{#5##1#5}}}%
    \@onelevel@sanitize\@tempb % <- Turn characters into their "12/other"-pendants.
                               %    This may be important with things like the 
                               %    inputenc-package which may make characters 
                               %    active/which give them catcode 13(active).
    \expandafter\UD@@@collectverbarg\expandafter{\@tempb}{#3}{#4}% <- this "spits out the result.
  }%
  \@tempb
}%
\newcommand\UD@@@collectverbarg[3]{\endgroup#2{#3{#1}}}%
%%================= End of code for \UDcollectverbarg =========================
\makeatother

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{tmpEnv}{Verbatim}{numbers=left,fontsize=\small}

\newbox\verbbox
\newcommand\scantokenssetvbox[2]{%
  \setbox#1=\vbox{%
    \begingroup\newlinechar=\endlinechar\relax\scantokens{\endgroup#2}%
  }%
  %Uncomment to typeset the box:
  %\ifvmode\else\par\fi\box#1%
  % You may wish to check for restricted horizontal mode and raise an error...
}

\UDcollectverbarg{\AtEndDocument}{\scantokenssetvbox{\verbbox}}|\begin{tmpEnv}
Some content to include at the end of every document using this cls.
\end{tmpEnv}|%

\begin{document}
Some text. Some text. Some text. 
\end{document}

This is a variant where the environment in question goes into a box which is clipped to zero height and zero depth and zero width - this way whatsits for delayed-writing things to external text-file at the time of shipping the page to pdf-file get carried out. But you have side-effects of placing another box into the document:
\makeatletter
%%======================Code for \UDcollectverbarg=============================
%% \UDcollectverbarg{<non-optional 1>}{<non-optional 2>}|<verbatim arg>|
%% 
%% reads <verbatim arg> under verbatim-catcode-regime and delivers:
%%
%%    <non-optional 1>{<non-optional 2>{<verbatim arg>}}
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% \UDcollectverbarg*{<non-optional 1>}{<non-optional 2>}|<verbatim arg>|
%% 
%% reads <verbatim arg> under verbatim-catcode-regime and delivers:
%%
%%    <non-optional 1>{<non-optional 2>{|<verbatim arg>|}}
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Instead of using verbatim-delimiter | or the like the <verbatim arg> can 
%% be nested in braces.
%%
%% You cannot use percent or spaces or horizontal tab as verbatim-delimiter.
%%
%% You can use <non-optional 1> for nesting calls to \UDcollectverbarg.
%%
%% The unstarred variant removes the verbatim-delimiters/braces that surround
%% <verbatim arg>.
%% The starred variant keeps the verbatim-delimiters/braces that surround
%% <verbatim arg>.
%% Reason: When you feed things to \scantokens you don't need the verbatim-
%%         delimiters.
%%         When you use things for writing to temporary files and reading back
%%         verbatimized, you may need them.
%%=============================================================================
\@ifdefinable\UDcollectverbarg{%
  \DeclareRobustCommand\UDcollectverbarg{%
    \@ifstar{\UD@collectverbarg{\@secondoftwo}}{\UD@collectverbarg{\@firstoftwo}}%
  }%
}%
\newcommand\UD@collectverbarg[3]{%
  % #1 - indicator whether to remove/keep the verb-delimiter (\@firstoftwo/\@secondoftwo)
  % #2 - non-optional 1
  % #3 - non-optional 2
  \begingroup
  \let\do\@makeother % <- this and the next line switch to
  \dospecials        %    verbatim-category-code-régime.
  \catcode`\{=1      % <- give opening curly brace the usual catcode so a 
                     %    curly-brace-balanced argument can be gathered in
                     %    case of the first thing of the verbatimized-argument 
                     %    being a curly opening brace.
  \catcode`\ =10     % <- give space and horizontal tab the usual catcode so \UD@@collectverbarg
  \catcode`\^^I=10   %    cannot catch a space or a horizontal tab as its 4th undelimited argument.
                     %    (Its 4th undelimited argument denotes the verbatim-
                     %     syntax-delimiter in case of not gathering a
                     %     curly-brace-nested argument.)
  \catcode`\%=14     % <- make percent comment.
  \kernel@ifnextchar\bgroup
  {% seems a curly-brace-nested argument is to be picked:
    \catcode`\}=2    % <- give closing curly brace the usual catcode also.
    \UD@@collectverbarg{#1}{\@firstoftwo}{#2}{#3}{}%
  }{% seems an argument with verbatim-syntax-delimiter is to be picked:
    \do\{% <- give opening curly brace the verbatim-catcode again.
    \UD@@collectverbarg{#1}{\@secondoftwo}{#2}{#3}%
  }%
}%
\newcommand\UD@@collectverbarg[5]{%
  % #1 - indicator whether to remove/keep the verb-delimiter (\@firstoftwo/\@secondoftwo)
  % #2 - indicator whether braces or verb-delimiter (\@firstoftwo/\@secondoftwo)
  % #3 - non-optional 1
  % #4 - non-optional 2
  % #5 - verb-delimiter or emptiness
  \do\ %   <- Now that \UD@@collectverbarg has the delimiter or
  \do\^^I%    emptiness in its 4th arg, give space and horizontal tab
         %    the verbatim-catcode again.
  \do\^^M% <- Give the carriage-return-character the verbatim-catcode.
  \do\%%   <- Give the percent-character the verbatim-catcode.
  \long\def\@tempb##1#5{%
    #1{\def\@tempb{##1}}{#2{\def\@tempb{{##1}}}{\def\@tempb{#5##1#5}}}%
    \@onelevel@sanitize\@tempb % <- Turn characters into their "12/other"-pendants.
                               %    This may be important with things like the 
                               %    inputenc-package which may make characters 
                               %    active/which give them catcode 13(active).
    \expandafter\UD@@@collectverbarg\expandafter{\@tempb}{#3}{#4}% <- this "spits out the result.
  }%
  \@tempb
}%
\newcommand\UD@@@collectverbarg[3]{\endgroup#2{#3{#1}}}%
%%================= End of code for \UDcollectverbarg =========================
\makeatother

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{trimclip}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{tmpEnv}{Verbatim}{numbers=left,fontsize=\small}

\newbox\verbbox
\makeatletter
\newcommand\scantokenssetvbox[2]{%
  \setbox#1=\vbox{%
    \begingroup\newlinechar=\endlinechar\relax\scantokens{\endgroup#2}%
  }%
  %Just in case - who knows what else already is in the \AtEndDocument-hook...
  \ifhmode\@bsphack\clipbox*{0pt 0pt 0pt 0pt}{\box#1}\@esphack
  \else\clipbox*{0pt 0pt 0pt 0pt}{\box#1}\fi
}%
\makeatother

\UDcollectverbarg{\AtEndDocument}{\scantokenssetvbox{\verbbox}}|\begin{tmpEnv}
Some content to include at the end of every document using this cls.
\end{tmpEnv}|%

\begin{document}
Some text. Some text. Some text. 
\end{document}

This is another variant where the environment in question goes into a box which is clipped to zero height and zero depth and zero width - this way whatsits for delayed-writing things to external text-file at the time of shipping the page to pdf-file get carried out. But you have side-effects of placing another box into the document. The difference to the previous variant is that some infrastructure is added for appending/prepending verbatim material to the content of the environment:
\makeatletter
%%======================Code for \UDcollectverbarg=============================
%% \UDcollectverbarg{<non-optional 1>}{<non-optional 2>}|<verbatim arg>|
%% 
%% reads <verbatim arg> under verbatim-catcode-regime and delivers:
%%
%%    <non-optional 1>{<non-optional 2>{<verbatim arg>}}
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% \UDcollectverbarg*{<non-optional 1>}{<non-optional 2>}|<verbatim arg>|
%% 
%% reads <verbatim arg> under verbatim-catcode-regime and delivers:
%%
%%    <non-optional 1>{<non-optional 2>{|<verbatim arg>|}}
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Instead of using verbatim-delimiter | or the like the <verbatim arg> can 
%% be nested in braces.
%%
%% You cannot use percent or spaces or horizontal tab as verbatim-delimiter.
%%
%% You can use <non-optional 1> for nesting calls to \UDcollectverbarg.
%%
%% The unstarred variant removes the verbatim-delimiters/braces that surround
%% <verbatim arg>.
%% The starred variant keeps the verbatim-delimiters/braces that surround
%% <verbatim arg>.
%% Reason: When you feed things to \scantokens you don't need the verbatim-
%%         delimiters.
%%         When you use things for writing to temporary files and reading back
%%         verbatimized, you may need them.
%%=============================================================================
\@ifdefinable\UDcollectverbarg{%
  \DeclareRobustCommand\UDcollectverbarg{%
    \@ifstar{\UD@collectverbarg{\@secondoftwo}}{\UD@collectverbarg{\@firstoftwo}}%
  }%
}%
\newcommand\UD@collectverbarg[3]{%
  % #1 - indicator whether to remove/keep the verb-delimiter (\@firstoftwo/\@secondoftwo)
  % #2 - non-optional 1
  % #3 - non-optional 2
  \begingroup
  \let\do\@makeother % <- this and the next line switch to
  \dospecials        %    verbatim-category-code-régime.
  \catcode`\{=1      % <- give opening curly brace the usual catcode so a 
                     %    curly-brace-balanced argument can be gathered in
                     %    case of the first thing of the verbatimized-argument 
                     %    being a curly opening brace.
  \catcode`\ =10     % <- give space and horizontal tab the usual catcode so \UD@@collectverbarg
  \catcode`\^^I=10   %    cannot catch a space or a horizontal tab as its 4th undelimited argument.
                     %    (Its 4th undelimited argument denotes the verbatim-
                     %     syntax-delimiter in case of not gathering a
                     %     curly-brace-nested argument.)
  \catcode`\%=14     % <- make percent comment.
  \kernel@ifnextchar\bgroup
  {% seems a curly-brace-nested argument is to be picked:
    \catcode`\}=2    % <- give closing curly brace the usual catcode also.
    \UD@@collectverbarg{#1}{\@firstoftwo}{#2}{#3}{}%
  }{% seems an argument with verbatim-syntax-delimiter is to be picked:
    \do\{% <- give opening curly brace the verbatim-catcode again.
    \UD@@collectverbarg{#1}{\@secondoftwo}{#2}{#3}%
  }%
}%
\newcommand\UD@@collectverbarg[5]{%
  % #1 - indicator whether to remove/keep the verb-delimiter (\@firstoftwo/\@secondoftwo)
  % #2 - indicator whether braces or verb-delimiter (\@firstoftwo/\@secondoftwo)
  % #3 - non-optional 1
  % #4 - non-optional 2
  % #5 - verb-delimiter or emptiness
  \do\ %   <- Now that \UD@@collectverbarg has the delimiter or
  \do\^^I%    emptiness in its 4th arg, give space and horizontal tab
         %    the verbatim-catcode again.
  \do\^^M% <- Give the carriage-return-character the verbatim-catcode.
  \do\%%   <- Give the percent-character the verbatim-catcode.
  \long\def\@tempb##1#5{%
    #1{\def\@tempb{##1}}{#2{\def\@tempb{{##1}}}{\def\@tempb{#5##1#5}}}%
    \@onelevel@sanitize\@tempb % <- Turn characters into their "12/other"-pendants.
                               %    This may be important with things like the 
                               %    inputenc-package which may make characters 
                               %    active/which give them catcode 13(active).
    \expandafter\UD@@@collectverbarg\expandafter{\@tempb}{#3}{#4}% <- this "spits out the result.
  }%
  \@tempb
}%
\newcommand\UD@@@collectverbarg[3]{\endgroup#2{#3{#1}}}%
%%================= End of code for \UDcollectverbarg =========================
\makeatother

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{trimclip}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{tmpEnv}{Verbatim}{numbers=left,fontsize=\small}

\makeatletter
\newbox\MYverbbox
\newtoks\MYverbtoks
\global\MYverbtoks={}%
\newcommand\exchange[2]{#2#1}%
\@ifdefinable\stopromannumeral{\chardef\stopromannumeral=`\^^00}%
\begingroup
\catcode`\^^M=12\relax%
\@firstofone{%
  \endgroup%
  \newcommand\@@appendtoverbtoks[1]{\global\MYverbtoks=\expandafter{\the\MYverbtoks#1^^M}\@esphack}%
  \newcommand\@@prependtoverbtoks[1]{%
    \global\MYverbtoks=%
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\expandafter\exchange\expandafter{\the\MYverbtoks}{#1^^M}}%
    \@esphack%
  }%
}%
\newcommand\appendtoverbtoks{\@bsphack\UDcollectverbarg{\@firstofone}{\@@appendtoverbtoks}}%
\newcommand\prependtoverbtoks{\@bsphack\UDcollectverbarg{\@firstofone}{\@@prependtoverbtoks}}%
\newcommand\scantokenssetvbox[4]{%
  \setbox#2=\vbox{%
    \begingroup\newlinechar=\endlinechar\relax\scantokens{\endgroup#3#1#4}%
  }%
  %---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  %Just in case - who knows what else already is in the \AtEndDocument-hook...
  \ifhmode\@bsphack\clipbox*{0pt 0pt 0pt 0pt}{\box#2}\@esphack
  \else\clipbox*{0pt 0pt 0pt 0pt}{\box#2}\fi
  %---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  %Uncomment to typeset the box:
  %\ifvmode\else\par\fi\box#2%
  %You may wish to check for restricted horizontal mode and raise an error...
}%

\UDcollectverbarg{\AtEndDocument}{\prependtoverbtoks}|This is at the begin of the environment.|%
\UDcollectverbarg{\AtEndDocument}{\appendtoverbtoks}|This is at the end of the environment.|%
\UDcollectverbarg{%
  \UDcollectverbarg{\AtEndDocument}%
}{\expandafter\scantokenssetvbox\expandafter{\the\MYverbtoks}{\MYverbbox}}|\begin{tmpEnv}
||\end{tmpEnv}|%
\appendtoverbtoks{Some content to include at the end of every document using this cls.
Here stuff can be prepended/appended.}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Some \appendtoverbtoks|This is appended 1.| text. Some text. Some \prependtoverbtoks|This is prepended 1.| text.
Some \appendtoverbtoks*This is appended 2.* text. Some text. Some \prependtoverbtoks{This is prepended 2.} text.
\end{document}


Let's address your comment

But I'm not sure how to get the \@verbContent  to expand inside... something like: \expandafter\UDcollectverbarg\expandafter{\AtEndDocument}\expandafter{\scantokenssetvbox\expandafter{\verbbox}}|\expandafter\begin{tmpEnv} \@verbContent \end{tmpEnv}|% To expand \@verbContent before executing all the other parts - except obviously that doesn't work since I can't get the \expandafter sequence right... assuming that approach could even work.

(In case you are interested: I tried to explain a few things and tricks about \expandafter in my answer to How can I know the number of expandafters when appending to a csname macro?.)
You'd need to insert \expandafter to have TeX "hop" over each token until reaching the token that shall be expanded first:
\expandafter\UDcollectverbarg
\expandafter{%
\expandafter\AtEndDocument
\expandafter}%
\expandafter{%
\expandafter\scantokenssetvbox
\expandafter{%
\expandafter\verbbox%
\expandafter}%
\expandafter}%
\expandafter|%
\expandafter\begin
\expandafter{%
\expandafter t%
\expandafter m%
\expandafter p%
\expandafter E%
\expandafter n%
\expandafter v%
\expandafter}%
\@verbContent
\end{tmpEnv}|%`

But this wouldn't work out because things that should be part of the verbatim-argument, namely
\begin
{%
t%
m%
p%
E%
n%
v%
}%

would erroneously be tokenized in normal catcode-régime in the course of doing the \expandafter-hopping.
Therefore I suggest collecting the begin and the end of the environment into separate verbatim-arguments and combining the environment from these arguments and what is stored in \@verbContent:
\UDcollectverbarg{%
  \UDcollectverbarg{\AtEndDocument}%
}{\expandafter\scantokenssetvbox\expandafter{\@verbContent}{\verbbox}}|\begin{tmpEnv}
||\end{tmpEnv}|%

This yields:
\UDcollectverbarg{\AtEndDocument}{\expandafter\scantokenssetvbox\expandafter{\@verbContent}{\verbbox}{\begin{tmpEnv}^^M}}|\end{tmpEnv}|

, hereby \begin{tmpEnv}^^M} denoting explicit character tokens that got tokenized in verbatim-catcode-régime.
This in turn yields:
\AtEndDocument{\expandafter\scantokenssetvbox\expandafter{\@verbContent}{\verbbox}{\begin{tmpEnv}^^M}{\end{tmpEnv}}}

, hereby \begin{tmpEnv}^^M} and \end{tmpEnv} denoting explicit character tokens that got tokenized in verbatim-catcode-régime.
Here \scantokenssetvbox can be a macro which takes 4 arguments ad sets the box #2 to the result of typesetting the result of \scantokens{#3#1#4} whereby #3 is the start of the environment, #1 is the content of \@verbContent and thus the tokens accumulated as the content of the environment and #4 is the end of the environment.

This was exactly what I was asking for, and works perfectly according to what I asked for!
Out of curiosity, is there a nice way to put a dummy macro inside the env where you currently have "Some Content to include..." so that a user can add to that dummy macro to append stuff into this hook in the future? (If not, it's not a big deal, but it would make my code a lot more readable if I could append code to such a dummy macro occasionally instead of having a huge brick of code in one spot). I imagine a suitable sequence of "expandafter" macros would do it, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Just to be clear, I'll mark this as accepted in a few hours - just wanted to hopefully give time for any updated/edits to address my previous comment (one way or the other).
Thanks again U.D. You continue to be the dark wizard to help me in my weird TeX incantations!

I don't do this for the upvotes, I do this for showing off and for helping with getting the job done, so don't accept too quick. Maybe answers better than mine arrive. As the environment processes things verbatim, macros inside the environment might not get executed. But you can have a mechanism for accumulating verbatim material e.g. in a token-register and at the end of the LaTeX-run using the content of the token-register when putting together the sequence of tokens that form the environment inclusive starting-command, environment-content and ending-command. ...

and ending-command. ... I can edit my answer and address the issue if you like, but maybe writing to auxiliary file for accumulating material might be a viable option as well.

The cls file already has a lot of stuff getting written to external file (which I am also trying to clean up), so I'm hoping to avoid that if I can, but willing if needed.
I was thinking about using something like:
\newcommand{\@addToVerb}[1]{     \let\oldHook\@verbContent     \def\@verbContent{     \oldHook      #1     } } (I'm writing this off the top of my head, so it probably needs to be fixed for expansion timing, like using \let instead of \def or such things).
Then using @addToVerb to append new stuff to the @verbContent container, then expand @verbContent inside your cmd

But I'm not sure how to get the @verbContent to expand inside... something like:
\expandafter\UDcollectverbarg\expandafter{\AtEndDocument}\expandafter{\scantokenssetvbox\expandafter{\verbbox}}|\expandafter\begin{tmpEnv} \@verbContent \end{tmpEnv}|%
To expand \@verbContent before executing all the other parts - except obviously that doesn't work since I can't get the \expandafter sequence right... assuming that approach could even work.

You are definitely a dark wizard of the highest caliber! The edited solution appears to work perfectly for what I'm after. As per your request I'll give it a few days to see if anyone comes up with another solution before I mark it as accepted (if I don't, feel free to remind me). Thanks again!
